# How to use permission level with JWT?

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 2.0 WebAPI which I'm securing with JWT as an HttpOnly cookie.
I'm now trying to implement a bitwise based permission level to each endpoint and I'm trying to understand if it can be done within the JWT cookie.
For example, I have a basic access level enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum AccessLevel
{
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Modify = 4,
    Delete = 8,
    FullControl = 15
}
```

Can I add a claim to my token like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("StudentsAccessLevel", "3"),
    new Claim("CoursesAccessLevel", "7")
};
```

And use it somehow in my `StudentsController` like that:

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    //obviously this is not the syntax, but is there a syntax that can be used like that?
    [Authorize("StudentsAccessLevel" & 1 > 0)]
    public  IActionResult Create() { }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize("StudentsAccessLevel" & 2 > 0)]
    public IActionResult Read() { }

    [HttpPut]
    [Authorize("StudentsAccessLevel" & 4 > 0)]
    public IActionResult Update() { }

    [HttpDelete()]
    [Authorize("StudentsAccessLevel" & 8 > 0)]
    public IActionResult DeleteAsync() { }
}
```

Comment: So you can get more info on handle claims like this straight form the documentation.  Here is a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1 If that isn't enough let me know

Comment: @rahicks, Thanks for the link, but this doesn't fit well with the implementation I'm looking for with operation access level. In the approach described in the link I'll have to add a claim for each operation (create, read, update, delete).

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way, but the first thing I would try is to override authorize Attribute [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460317(v=vs.118) ]  and make it work for your claims

Comment: @rahicks, your link gets 404 errror... Maybe I can use this [using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy)

Comment: yeah I adding ] at the end it should be fine

Comment: Looks like that would do the trick nicely

Answer (score 0):

In order to influence the scopes that actually get applied for a given user authentication according to the Role to which they belong, you could define a Rule in Auth0 Dashboard. Here is a really simple example:

```
function (user, context, callback) {

  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};

   if (user.app_metadata.role === "Administrator") {
     context.accessToken.scope = 'openid read:posts create:posts edit:posts';
   } else if (user.app_metadata.role === "User") {
  ...  // define likewise as needed..
   }

   callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Whether the role statically applied to the user profile or dynamically looked up etc, is less clear and will depend on your requirements. But if you set this up, you should receive a JWT access token with a payload containing something like the following (for the situation where the user authenticating had Administrator role.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGfAV.gif)

You can then secure your .NET Core API to verify the access token accordingly. If you are not using an API, then theoretically you "could" use the ID Token instead... (as the application itself is the consumer). But I have based the above on the understanding you wish to authorize a request against some API...?

Comment: Refer this: [Using Roles with the ASP.NET Core JWT middleware](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-roles-with-the-jwt-middleware/)